# When using linear approximation to estimate 1/4.002, what is the x in L(x) = f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, approximation, linear-approximation

Sorry in advance for the formatting I've never used this site before.

I'm asked to use linear approximation to estimate 1/4.002

I found the derivative = -1/(x^2)

and I believe f(x) is 1/4

so a = 4

and L(x) = f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)

therefore: L(x) = 1/4 - (-1/16)(x-4)

But what is the x? I'm thinking its 0.002 but that doesn't seem right cause it need to be close to 4. Is it just 4.002?

Answer (score 1):

See, the first degree approximation to $f(x)$ is given by $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$.

You want the value of $f(4.002)$, where $f(x) = \frac 1x$. $a$ is a value close to $x$ such that $f(a)$ is easy to calculate. So in your case, $a=4$ is desirable.

Now, if you plug in the formula with $a = 4$ and $x = 4.002$, you get:
$$
f(4) + f'(4)(4.002-4) = \frac 14 - \frac{0.002}{16} = 0.249875.
$$

This is the first degree approximation to $\frac 1{4.002}$. The actual value is somewhat like $0.249875062...$ so you are actually correct to six decimal places for even a first degree approximation.

Comment: Thanks, Best Regards!

Comment: You are welcome. If your question is answered correctly, you may upvote any of he above answers, and accept any one. This is so that we can close this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is just 4.002. You are estimating $f(x)=1/x$ at $x=4.002$ by evaluating $L(x)$ there instead.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to be sure!